# Call <update> handler from within <block>

Tags: layout, update-handle

I'm still pretty new to Magento (1.9 EE) so some of my terminology may be incorrect, apologies if so.

Anyway, in one of my layout XML files, I have a custom block which I can include using the `update` tag, something like

```
<custom_block>
    <block name="...">
        ...
    </block>
</custom_block>

<another_block_1>
    <update handle="custom_block" />
</another_block_1>
```

This all works fine. However, when I try to call the `update` from within a `block` tag, it doesn't work, something like:

```
<another_block_2>
    <block name="sub_another_block_2" ...>
        <update handle="custom_block" />
    </block>
</another_block_2>
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? A colleague mentioned that `update` might not be the correct tag.

Comment: Is there anything specific you're trying to update? If you put this question in context we might be able to help you. E.g what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @AndréFerraz . I'm basically trying to have a re-usable block in my layout. So, custom_block above will be used twice in the same layout: once in the first/working format another_block_1, then the second time, I need it within the sub_another_block_2 section, which is part of another_block_2. Hope that makes sense!

(I edited the original text to add _1 and _2 to another_block, for clarity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only meaningful occurrence o `update` and `handle` I found is in the [Layout update class](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php#L388).
What this method does, is to parse the merged layout handle and if it finds child nodes with the name `update` and the attribute `handle` it merges that handle to the current handle.
As you can see it only looks for `update` nodes as direct child nodes of the main handle tag. It does not look for it inside the blocks or any other tags you might have.
In conclusion, no, adding update handles inside blocks does not work.